# How use MICR / E13-B Fonts in HTML Page

Tags: html, css, fonts, micr

I want to show my cheque numbers like "MICR / E13-B Fonts". 
How could i display it using css.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 3):

Most modern browsers support embedded fonts (even IE if you provide them in the right format):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/06/modern-css-layouts-part-2-the-essential-techniques/#moderncss-fonts

(Other alternatives such as image replacement are also mentioned in that article)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `font-face` to define a font, then use that defined font as you would use any other font in CSS.

See http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face#Browser_compatibility